# Does Windows 10 "text suggestion" have a hotkey to accept first suggested word?

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to test this feature but not being able to quickly select the suggestion, instead of clicking it, is going to slow down my typing speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing the <kbd>up</kbd> arrow key will select the first suggestion, then you can press <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm.